# How to avoid sigkill error 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sigkill

I am trying to build an algorithm which first builds a power set of around 100 symbols excluding null set and repeated elements.
Then for each item in the list of power set it reads data file and evaluates the Sharpe Ratio (Return/Risk). 
Results are then appended to a list and at last the program gives the best combination of symbols that would result in highest Sharpe Ratio.

Following is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from itertools import chain, combinations
import operator
import time as t
#ASSUMPTION
#EQUAL ALLOCATION OF RESOURCES

t0 = t.time()
start_date = '2016-06-01'
end_date = '2017-08-18'

allocation = 170000
usesymbols=['PAEL','TPL','SING','DCL','POWER','FCCL','DGKC','LUCK',
          'THCCL','PIOC','GWLC','CHCC','MLCF','FLYNG','EPCL',
          'LOTCHEM','SPL','DOL','NRSL','AGL','GGL','ICL','AKZO','ICI',
           'WAHN','BAPL','FFC','EFERT','FFBL','ENGRO','AHCL','FATIMA',
          'EFOODS','QUICE','ASC','TREET','ZIL','FFL','CLOV',
          'BGL','STCL','GGGL','TGL','GHGL','OGDC','POL','PPL','MARI',
          'SSGC','SNGP','HTL','PSO','SHEL','APL','HASCOL','RPL','MERIT',
          'GLAXO','SEARL','FEROZ','HINOON','ABOT','KEL','JPGL','EPQL',
          'HUBC','PKGP','NCPL','LPL','KAPCO','TSPL','ATRL','BYCO','NRL','PRL',
          'DWSM','SML','MZSM','IMSL','SKRS','HWQS','DSFL','TRG','PTC','TELE',
          'WTL','MDTL','AVN','NETSOL','SYS','HUMNL','PAKD',
          'ANL','CRTM','NML','NCL','GATM','CLCPS','GFIL','CHBL',
          'DFSM','KOSM','AMTEX','HIRAT','NCML','CTM','HMIM',
           'CWSM','RAVT','PIBTL','PICT','PNSC','ASL',
          'DSL','ISL','CSAP','MUGHAL','DKL','ASTL','INIL']

cost_matrix = []

def data(symbols):
    dates=pd.date_range(start_date,end_date) 
    df=pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp=pd.read_csv('/home/furqan/Desktop/python_data/{}.csv'.format(str(symbol)),usecols=['Date','Close'],
                            parse_dates=True,index_col='Date',na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Close': symbol})
        df=df.join(df_temp)
        df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
        df=df.fillna(method='bfill')
    return df

def mat_alloc_auto(symbols):

    n = len(symbols)
    mat_alloc = np.zeros((n,n), dtype='float')
    for i in range(0,n):
        mat_alloc[i,i] = allocation / n
    return mat_alloc

def compute_daily_returns(df):
    """Compute and return the daily return values."""
    daily_returns=(df/df.shift(1))-1
    df=df.fillna(value=0)
    daily_returns=daily_returns[1:]
    daily_returns = np.array(daily_returns)
    return daily_returns

def port_eval(matrix_alloc,daily_return_matrix):
    risk_free = 0
    amount_matrix = [allocation]
    return_mat = np.dot(daily_return_matrix,matrix_alloc)
    return_mat = np.sum(return_mat, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    return_mat = np.divide(return_mat,amount_matrix)
    mat_average = np.mean(return_mat)
    mat_std = np.std(return_mat, ddof=1)
    sharpe_ratio = ((mat_average-risk_free)/mat_std) * math.sqrt(252)
    return return_mat, sharpe_ratio, mat_average


def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

power_set = list(powerset(usesymbols))
len_power = len(power_set)
sharpe = []
for j in range(0, len_power):
    df_01 = data(power_set[j])
    matrix_allocation = mat_alloc_auto(power_set[j])
    daily_return_mat = compute_daily_returns(df_01)
    return_matrix, sharpe_ratio_val, matrix_average = port_eval(matrix_allocation, daily_return_mat)
    sharpe.append(sharpe_ratio_val)


max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(sharpe), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print('Maximum sharpe ratio occurs from ',power_set[max_index], ' value = ', max_value)

t1=t.time()
print('exec time is ', t1-t0, 'seconds')
```

The above code results in a sigkill error 9. 
After research I understood that it is because process allocates too much memory putting pressures on OS.
So I tried running same code on HP Z600 workstation but it takes a lot of time plus the machine is freezes.
My question is how can I make my code more efficient to get instant results.

Comment: Are you aware that the power set of a set of 100 elements has `2 ** 100` elements?  That's too many to fit into memory.  In fact, it's billions of times the storage on all hard disks in the world combined.

Comment: As to your question how to get "instant results", you can't use brute force for this problem.  You need some discrete optimization algorithm, which is a complex topic.  The best algorithm depends on the exact mathematical properties of the Sharpe Ratio.  Maybe you can get away with dynamic programming, but I can't tell from a quick glance.

Comment: Take your time. See if you can help me with this.

Comment: I guess you will have to figure this out yourself. :)

Comment: Can we apply multiprocessing to work around this problem?

Comment: No, you can't brute force this problem.  There are just too many configurations to brute force.  Using multiprocessing only gives you a speedup proportional to the number of cores you have available, so maybe 8 or so, which doesn't help.  You need a better algorithm, and working one out requires a good understanding of the mathematical properties of the problem.  It's unlikely anybody will have time to do this work for you.

Comment: Sure thanks. Will try myself to make it better.

Comment: I was hoping this post would elicit some advice on memory management. Instead we get the usual low-resolution comments nagging you about asking the wrong question. You clearly do need to scale down your ambitions w.r.t. memory usage, but let's hope we get some informative feedback on how to avoid SIGKILL 9 at some point, I don't know, like how to clear caches programmatically or something along those lines. Good luck.